# Tkinter won't recognize key presses

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to write a program so that a car is drawn moving along the screen, and the up and down arrow keys can change the speed of the car. However, when I press either key, neither command is called. I've tried changing the bind_all and focus lines to self.canvas but that hasn't worked either. How can I fix this?

```
class racingCar:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Racing Car")

        self.cWidth = 500
        self.cHeight = 200
        self.canvas = Canvas(window, width = self.cWidth, height = self.cHeight, bg = "white")
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.x = 0
        self.y = self.cHeight
        self.drawCar(self.x, self.y)

        self.dx = 5
        self.sleepTime = 50
        self.animate()

        window.bind_all("<Up>", self.increaseSpeed)
        window.bind_all("<Down>", self.decreaseSpeed)
        window.focus()

        window.mainloop()

    def drawCar(self, x, y):
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x, y - 20, x + 50, y - 10, fill = "yellow", tags = "car")
        self.canvas.create_oval(x + 10, y - 10, x + 20, y, fill = "black", tags = "car")
        self.canvas.create_oval(x + 30, y - 10, x + 40, y, fill = "black", tags = "car")
        self.canvas.create_polygon([x + 10, y - 20, x + 20, y - 30, x + 30, y - 30, x + 40, y - 20], fill = "blue", tags = "car")

    def increaseSpeed(self, event):
        print("pressed up")
        self.dx += 2.5

    def decreaseSpeed(self, event):
        print("pressed down")
        if self.dx > 0:
            self.dx -= 2.5

    def animate(self):
        while not self.dx == 0:
            self.canvas.move("car", self.dx, 0)
            self.canvas.after(self.sleepTime)
            self.canvas.update()
            if self.x < self.cWidth + 10:
                self.x += self.dx
            else:
                self.x = -60
                self.canvas.delete("car")
                self.drawCar(self.x, self.y)
racingCar()
```

Comment: Try putting the function racingCar() in a forever loop? I'm assuming that you need to be constantly checking for keypresses.

Comment: Doesn't mainloop() do that already? Or do I have to call eventloop() as well?

Comment: My guess is the while loop is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `while` or `sleep` ever in the same thread tkinter is running in.

In this case how you are using `after()` it is functioning exactly like `sleep`.

Because tkinter is single threaded those methods will block the mainloop and nothing else can happen until the loop is ended or sleep has ended. The reason your canvas is updated is because you are calling update in the while loop but your events are still being blocked.

To fix this use `after()` as it is meant for this kind of loop in tkinter.

I have updated your code to use `after()` and cleaned it up a bit to more closely follow PEP8 style guide. let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk


class RacingCar(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Racing Car")

        self.c_width = 500
        self.c_height = 200
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=self.c_width, height=self.c_height, bg="white")
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.x = 0
        self.y = self.c_height
        self.draw_car(self.x, self.y)

        self.dx = 5
        self.after_time = 50
        self.animate()

        self.bind("<Up>", self.increase_speed)
        self.bind("<Down>", self.decrease_speed)

    def draw_car(self, x, y):
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x, y - 20, x + 50, y - 10, fill="yellow", tags="car")
        self.canvas.create_oval(x + 10, y - 10, x + 20, y, fill="black", tags="car")
        self.canvas.create_oval(x + 30, y - 10, x + 40, y, fill="black", tags="car")
        self.canvas.create_polygon([x + 10, y - 20, x + 20, y - 30, x + 30, y - 30, x + 40, y - 20],
                                   fill="blue", tags="car")

    def increase_speed(self, _):
        print("pressed up")
        self.dx += 2.5

    def decrease_speed(self, _):
        print("pressed down")
        if self.dx > 0:
            self.dx -= 2.5

    def animate(self):
        if self.dx != 0:
            self.canvas.move("car", self.dx, 0)
            if self.x < self.c_width + 10:
                self.x += self.dx
            else:
                self.x = -60
                self.canvas.delete("car")
                self.draw_car(self.x, self.y)
            self.after(self.after_time, self.animate)


RacingCar().mainloop()
```